# ASP.NET visual web part + AJAX, can't make it working

Tags: c#, ajax, sharepoint, asp.net-ajax, web-parts

I was trying to implement this simple example http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

But it doesn't work, it gives

```
Failed to load http://site/path/path/pagename.aspx/GetCurrentTime resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Client side

```
<script src="http://.../jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pagename.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
            data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
    onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
```

Server (.cs file)

```
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
        {
            return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
                + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function `failure` in the ajax definition. You need to rename it to `error`. Check the source : [**jQuery.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**P.S** also I advice you to use `console.log`, not alerts. `console.log` your name parameter to see if return proper value. Check [**JSON.stringify**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for creating your data.

Comment: Yea, now error just returns 'undefined'. But I still can't understand where is the problem. I was debugging and server method is not called.

Comment: @HoTTab1CH I suppose you have problem in the data. Write simple string in the instead of your jquery code.

Comment: I did, same error. Maybe there should be something else added on server side?